# How is alpha added in CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

Consider the following three divs:

```css
.example-single {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #04B43188;
}

.example-single:hover {
  background-color: #04B431CC;
}

.example-parent {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #04B43188;
}

.example-child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.example-child:hover {
  background-color: #04B43144;
  /* what alpha is needed here?! */
}

.reference {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #04B431CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-single">Single
</div>

<div class="reference">Reference
</div>

<div class="example-parent">
  <div class="example-child">Nested
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to have both the single and the nested `div` to have the same color when hovering (in this case to match the reference `div`). For the single div this is easy, but for the nested divs the colors of the parent and child are overlayed. How do I calculate the alpha value I need to give the child to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have two black elements overlapping, 50% opacity each, the overlapping section would have the alpha of (1-(0.5*0.5))*100, or 75% alpha.

[image: Example of two opaque, overlapping divs with a background of #000000 and alpha of 50%]

In your case, the added alpha of #XXXXXX88 (decimal value of 136, or 53% of 255) and #XXXXXXCC (decimal value of 204, or 80% of 255) would be (1-(0.53*0.8))*100 = 57.6% (or #XXXXXX93).

I personally recommend using [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()) values instead of hex values for readability where you can define alpha as decimals instead of hexadecimals.